# Two React useEffect hooks accessing the window onscroll?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am new to React dev so this may be something simple I am missing with hooks.
Using a template, I have used a header bar which shrinks in height if you scroll down in the page far enough (i.e it is only at max height if you scroll to the top).

I have been customising a sidebar to go along with the headerbar, and I'm trying to get the items within it to also move up when the bottom of the headerbar moves up.

The app bar uses a pre-made function:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------

export default function useOffSetTop(top: number) {
  const [offsetTop, setOffSetTop] = useState(false);
  const isTop = top || 100;

  useEffect(() => {
    window.onscroll = () => {
      if (window.pageYOffset > isTop) {
        setOffSetTop(true);
      } else {
        setOffSetTop(false);
      }
    };
    return () => {
      window.onscroll = null;
    };
  }, [isTop]);

  return offsetTop;
}
```

Then you can just import it, assign a constant bool to `useOffSetTop(HEADER.DASHBOARD_DESKTOP_HEIGHT)` and base the layout on the state of that const.

In the app bar it controls the height, so in the nav bar I made it control he height of an empty .
It does work, but the app bar stops working.
I do have hot-reload on and if I make a change to the app bar it starts working but the nav bar stops working.

I guess it is just because whichever loads last is the one which binds something to window.onscroll and the other is wiped.

I am just wondering how I could change this function or restructure the code so that this could be imported by multiple components on the same page - possibly without having to just import it higher up and pass the true/false value down through the components?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are actually "overriding" the onScroll function (or replacing it) instead of listening for the event.

by doing this

window.onScroll = null;

you are effectively overriding the onScroll function to do nothing.

Best to listen for the onscroll event.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export default function useOffSetTop(top: number) {
  const [offsetTop, setOffSetTop] = useState(false);
  const isTop = top || 100;

  const handleOnScroll = () => {
   
    if (window.pageYOffset > isTop) {
      setOffSetTop(true);
    } else {
      setOffSetTop(false);
    }
  }
  

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', handleOnScroll )
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleOnScroll)
    };
  }, [isTop, handleOnScroll]);

  return offsetTop;
}
```